# how to send a message from client web page to 0mq server

Tags: javascript, zeromq

Is it possible to send directly message from JavaScript in client browser to 0mq?

If not in JavaScript, then I should use Flash or setup some http proxy server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0mq is not meant for Internet facing ports. There is a project called nullmq which does what you want though by translating from web protocols to zmq behind the firewall, while retaining zeromq like api on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it would be easiest to have your client browser make an `XMLHttpRequest()` to your web application and then have your web application talk to your 0MQ infrastructure.

There is a [javascript/flash binding](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajavascript) for 0MQ, but I've never worked with it myself so I can't comment on stability or anything.

If you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish we might be able to suggest viable alternatives.

Comment: I'm developing some advert system and I need to log peoples activity.
I was thinking if can can use direct 0mq boost.

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets on the client-side if you want a persistent connection and use a websocket server like tornado or socket.io to relay the messages to zmq and back.